# Pre-caching Shiny renderCachedPlot automatically

Tags: r, caching, plot, shiny

I am wondering if it is possible to pre-cache a set of initial inputs for renderCachedPlot. I cannot figure out how to do this, I know that renderCachedPlot uses digest to generate the hash but it also uses a set of height + weight in a way that I can't figure out. And I can't figure it out from looking at the source code either.

My exact question was also asked here (with no solution):

https://community.rstudio.com/t/pre-caching-shiny-rendercachedplot-the-first-time-automatically/55892